# @Assert\Valid() on Entity, remove the validation on form

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, doctrine-orm, assert

I been searching online, couldn't find the answer to my problem.

I want to disable @Assert/Valid() on first field, if second field is selected by the user. right now validation is happening on both fields.

---

Form type

```
AppBundle/Form/ParcelType.php
class ParcelType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $user = 1;

        $builder
            //TODO if address is selected from history, then dont validate this field
            ->add('pickupAddressNew', new AddressType())

            ->add('pickupAddressHistory', 'entity', [
                'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Address',
                'property' => 'formatAddress',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($user) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('a')
                        ->where('a.user = :user')
                        ->andWhere('a.type = :type')
                        ->setParameter('user', $user)
                        ->setParameter('type', 'pickup')
                        ->orderBy('a.isDefault', 'DESC')
                        ->addOrderBy('a.id', 'DESC');
                }
            ]););

    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'parcel';
    }
}

AppBundle/Entity/Model/Parcel.php
class Parcel
{
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @Assert\Type(type="AppBundle\Entity\Address")
     * @Assert\Valid()
     */
    protected $pickupAddressNew;

    /**
     * @Assert\Type(type="AppBundle\Entity\Address")
     * @Assert\Valid()
     */
    protected $pickupAddressHistory;
...
}
```

Address

```
AppBundle/Entity/Address.php

class Address
{
...
private $id;

..
private $firstName;

   /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="field.address.blank")
     * @Assert\Length(
     *      min = 3,
     *      max = 255,
     *      minMessage = "field.address.min",
     *      maxMessage = "field.address.max"
     * )
     * @ORM\Column(name="format_address", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $address;
}
```

Comment: asserts will always apply to the entity if you configured them. if you need a conditional validation you can (as you did) use form eventlistener or implement @Assert\Callback in you entity to implement a conditional validation (would only use that for simple things).

If you have more complex validations following the conditional validation you could as well implement your own annotation validator to to achieve what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long search, I couldn't find any answer, but found another solution which will solve it. Sharing with community, so others can solve it quickly.

Remove @Assert/Valid() from the annotation and add following on the form type

```
public function buildForm(...) {
...
$form->add('pickupAddressNew', new AddressType(), [
                    'label' => 'form.label.pickupAddressNew',
                    'constraints' => new Valid()
                ])

// also add event listener 
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::SUBMIT, array($this, 'conditionValid'));

}
```

now create condition valid method on same formType class.

```
public function conditionValid (FormEvent $event)
    {
        $parcel = $event->getData();

        $form = $event->getForm();

        if ($parcel->getPickupAddressHistory() > 0)
        {
            $form->add('pickupAddressNew', new AddressType(), [
                'label' => 'form.label.pickupAddress'
            ]);
        }
    }
```

On this method, we check if second field has value and its selected, then recreate the first field without the validation rule, this will bypass the group validation.